# PHP Get value from database into selectbox

Tags: php, database, drop-down-menu

I have a problem to show my database values into a select box.

Here is my code

```
<select name="bugsolver">
<?php 
  if(count($yourBugs) > 0) 
  {
    foreach( $emails as $key=> $singleEmail)
    { ?>
  <option value="<?=$singleEmail['email']?>" selected='selected'> <?php echo $singleEmail['email']?></option>";

<?php }
} ?>

</select>
```

Comment: Would be nice to see your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look like this:

```
<select name="bugsolver">
  <?php 
  if(count($yourBugs) > 0):
    foreach( $emails as $key=> $singleEmail ):
  ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $singleEmail['email']; ?>"> 
        <?php echo $singleEmail['email']; ?>
      </option>

  <?php
    endforeach;
  endif;
  ?>
</select>
```

When your code is easy to read (at least for you) it's easier to find bugs. If above code still doesn't work, do `var_dump($yourBugs)` and `var_dump($emails)` to check if these values are properly set. You can have disabled short tags (`<?=`) or variables are just empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems be OK. Try to test for $emails instead $yourBugs to get more info:

```
<?php if (count($emails)) : // test if $emails have values ?>
<select name="bugsolver">
    foreach( $emails as $key=> $singleEmail) { /* ... */ }
</select>
<?php else : ?>
    There are no emails to select ($emails is empty)
<?php endif; ?>
```